# Limits and substitutions

Tags: limits, derivatives, substitution

I have seen the following performed during analysis of the limiting behaviour of real functions. consider
$$
f(x) = \frac{1-x^a}{1-x^b}
$$
with integers $a,b$. At the point $x\rightarrow 1$ the function is undefined. However, the limit can be found from L''Hospital's rule as
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) = \frac{ax^{a-1}}{bx^{b-1}}=\frac{a}{b}\bigg|_{x=1}
$$
Now, at this point, a substitution is made such that $x$ is replaced by $\xi =-1/\log x$ to arrive at
$$
\frac{1-e^{-a/\xi}}{1-e^{-b/\xi}}
$$
I am aware that $\log(1) = 0$; however, why can we substitute this expression in, and can any relevant function with the desired behaviour at $x=1$ be used?

Comment: What is the point of $\xi$? "why can we substitute this expression in" what?

Comment: Btw, for positive intergs $a,b$, $\frac{1-x^a}{1-x^b}=\frac{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{a-1}}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b-1}}=\frac{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{a-1}}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b-1}}\to \frac{\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^a}{\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_b}=\frac ab$

Comment: Your substitution is fine, but then you need to deal with $x\to 1^+$ and $x\to 1^-$ separately because they lead to $\xi\to-\infty $ and $\xi\to\infty $.

Comment: It is much easier to divide numerator and denominator by $1-x$ and use the standard limit formula $\lim\limits _{x\to a} \dfrac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons we like continuous functions is that they preserve limits of functions, so if $f$ is continuous, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$ (assuming the limit of $g$ exists). That means in particular, that if $-1/\log{x}$ applied to our function has some nice properties, then you can use it just as you noticed.

Answer (score 1):

One general theorem is following: suppose exists, finite or not, limits $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y \to b}F(x)$. If in some [punctured(deleted) neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) of $a$ holds $f(x) \ne b$, then in point $a$ exists limit of composition and holds
$$\lim\limits_{x \to a}F(f(x))=\lim\limits_{y \to b}F(x)$$

In your case, assuming $a,b \gt 1, a\ne b$, after applying L'Hospital you can directly put $x=1$ without any substitution.

If we want to use substitution of variables, without L'Hospital, then, for example, we can write
$$f(x) = \frac{1-x^a}{1-x^b} = \frac{1-(1+t)^a}{1-(1+t)^b}=\frac{\frac{1-(1+t)^a}{t}}{\frac{1-(1+t)^b}{t}}$$
and use limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^a-1}{t}=a$ for substitution $x=1+t$